# Where does Url rewrites go in Magento 2.4.2? (Programmatically)

Tags: url, magento, url-rewriting, magento2

right now I am learning Magento 2.4.2

I have created a page and the url for my page is: http://learningmagento.docker/pages/page/About

But I would like it to be:
http://learningmagento.docker/creatuity/why-creatuity

While there are plenty of docs on how to do this programatically all the tutorials seem to be missing the same info. Is this a simple script file or a class? Where does this file belong?

Would anyone be able to answer these questions or provide the proper documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a simple script file or a class? Where does this file belong?

It's neither a script file or a class.  You create rewrites via the Magento 2 admin (usually under the *Marketing* section). The data for these rewrite objects is stored in the `url_rewrite` table.

In addition to creating rewrites manually, many Magento features (products, CMS pages) will allow you to set a URL-ish field and Magento will create the data in the `url_rewrite` table for you.